# Remove Metaboxes

Tags: code

I try to remove metaboxes from non-admin for posts, pages, and add products page (WooCommerce), and this my code:

```
// ciusART Remove Metaboxes
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_metaboxes_for_non_admin');
function remove_metaboxes_for_non_admin(){
    if (!is_admin()){ // only remove for non admins
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_layout-settings', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_layout-settings', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_layout-settings', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_product-settings', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_product-settings', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_product-settings', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_sidebar', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_sidebar', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_sidebar', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_size-guide', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_size-guide', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_size-guide', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_header-image-background', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_header-image-background', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_header-image-background', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_footer-image-background', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_footer-image-background', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_footer-image-background', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer-image-background', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer-image-background', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer-image-background', 'products', 'advanced');
        // continue adding as necessary
    }
}
```

But this code not work, can you help me...

Thanks...

Comment: I believe you can use something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96679/21376) to simplify that code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will ever fire....

Is_admin() detects admin UI not admin priveleges... Try:

```
if (is_admin()) : 
function my_remove_meta_boxes()  { 
if( !current_user_can('manage_options') )  { 
    remove_meta_box(...);
}}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Change !is_admin() current user is administrator ,  is_admin() not check user but they check admin panel area

please change in your code

```
 add_action('admin_head', 'remove_metaboxes_for_non_admin');
function remove_metaboxes_for_non_admin(){
    global $current_user;
    if ($current_user->role[0]!='administrator')
    {
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_layout-settings', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_layout-settings', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_layout-settings', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_product-settings', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_product-settings', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_product-settings', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_sidebar', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_sidebar', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_sidebar', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_size-guide', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_size-guide', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_size-guide', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_header-image-background', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_header-image-background', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_header-image-background', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_footer-image-background', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_footer-image-background', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_footer-image-background', 'products', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer-image-background', 'post', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer-image-background', 'page', 'advanced');
        remove_meta_box('acf_acf_extended-footer-image-background', 'products', 'advanced');
        // continue adding as necessary
    }
}
```